# Geothermal system that will not always cycle down at set point

Tags: hvac

I have a Geothermal HVAC system (no outside unit). Occasionally it will continue to run well past the set point and not cycle off. It may do this once in a week or once in a few weeks. If I turn the system off completely and let it stand for 15 minutes or so, it will work just fine for a while, maybe a few hours or maybe several days. it is not the couple of degree plus or minus, it can be as much as 8 or 9 degrees lower than the set point in the cool mode. I have tightened all the contacts on the thermostat and it still does the same thing. Any suggestions.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you edit in some more info (e.g. make/model of the system and the controller)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Sounds like a sticking relay. Geothermal use in ground loops or water transfer I am curious how a geothermal would function without something outside the house?